# Stuck with Java Json with UUID key

Tags: java, json

How to parse json like this in java where key is randomly generate on server side.

```
[{"device":[{"f9f76590-cf64-11e2-8387-9c8e99238f40":{"number":"200","icon":"landline","status":"online","display_number":"","type":"Cellular"}},{"f9foghss0-cf64-11e2-8387-9c8e99238f40":{"number":"200","icon":"landline","status":"online","display_number":"","type":"Cellular"}}]}]
```

Comment: what API you are using to parse JSON?

Comment: How does the fact that the key is generated randomly changes the way you parse JSON? JSON is JSON. What's your *real* question?

Comment: i have tried to use Google gson.but problem is Key is randomly generated.

Comment: @JB Nizet
My real question is how can i map it on my POJO.

Comment: Probably you need to share your Pojo, to which you are trying to parse the JSOn to

Comment: Use a JsonParser to parse the JSON to a JsonElement, or use JsonDeserializer. In any case you won't be able to automaticall map this JSON structure to a POJO.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map it to a class. Rather you will have to parse the json using something like [Gson][1] to get the key and then iterate each key to get to the dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/) for your content and generate java classes out of it using [jsonschema2pojo](http://code.google.com/p/jsonschema2pojo/). You can then see that this content would be mapped to `Map<String, Object>` during deserialization

You could do it [online](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to map known keys to typed fields and dynamic keys to a map using e.g. this approach: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html